# Check if ImageView has image without calling getDrawable method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, drawable

The following line is throwing an OutOfMemoryException

```
if (null == myImage.getDrawable()){
  //...
}
```

Is there another way to check if an ImageView has a Drawable/Bitmap?

Comment: well then, I seem to have upset someone so early. My apologies. But the mystery behind your disapproval is not helping, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be work around. Call imageview.getWidth() or getHeight(). If the value is 0 then no image is loaded

Answer (score 1):

In this case, what i would do is make use of `setTag` and `getTag` on `ImageView`. First time in xml set the tag as empty and whenever you bind any drawable, set some value to the tag using `setTag().`

If tag has some value, assume that imageview is having a drawable and if the value is empty then the imageview is not having drawable.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Man, this sounds like a splendid idea. But I am using Picasso to load my image (using `resize(newSize,newSize)`)  and so it's not easy to know when to set the tag. But +1 because otherwise, I think this should work.

Comment: before calling the picasso loadImage() method, set the tag to the imageview with some value

Answer (score 1):

You have to watch your memory usage though, here's a quick and dirty solution

```
try {
   if (myImage.getDrawable() == null)
     doFoo();
   else
     doBar();
 } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
   //the ImageView definetely had some large content
     doBar();
 }
```

Comment: I am already doing that, but the problem is that `doBar` is then not executed if there is an error. Which is sort of ironic because I don't want to execute `doBar` if there is no image -- but if there is one, the execution is kind of crucial.

Comment: @KatedralPillon put the call in the `catch` clause?

Comment: @KatedralPillon well, I guess in this case there's only one elegant solution - make some considerations about your image loading mechanism and prevent the error from happening. If you are using Picasso then it's kinda strange that you are getting an OOM unless you ain't doing something wrong like creating multiple Picasso instances in a `List` or `GridView`. Try to use `.skipMemoryCache()` and also take a look at the Android Studio's Memory Monitor tool

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite ImageView class and fill some boolean value when setDrawable method called.

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {
    public boolean isImageSet = false;

    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
        if(bm != null)
            isImageSet = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I may very well end up doing this. The only problem is that now I have to go and use this custom view everywhere, including in the xml layout file otherwise I cannot cast it. +1 for the idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might only address the symptoms, but you could try adding android:largeHeap="true" in your androidmanifest application tag